# ASP.NET webservice: Obtain value from URL for operation

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have looked all over the net but cant seem to find a decent example.

In php we can use GET to pull in variables from the URL; how is this done in asmx?

```
[WebMethod(Description = "multiply two numbers")]
    public int mul(int num1, int num2)
    {
       //num1 = Request.QueryString["num1"];
       //num2 = Request.QueryString["num2"];
        return num1 * num2;

    }
```

I have inserted the following into the web.config file to enable GET:

```
<webServices>
<protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
    <add name="HttpPost"/>
</protocols> 
</webServices>
```

Comment: I found this very useful.

http://blog.dlwelch.com/?p=390

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how your calling the asmx client side, but on the web method you may need to add  ScriptMethod specifying "GET" explicitly.

```
    [WebMethod(Description = "multiply two numbers")]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public int mul(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return num1 * num2;

    }
```

Comment: I get this error: The type or namespace name 'ScriptMethod' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Add: using System.Web.Script.Services; to the top

Answer (score 1):

say the url is `http://www.yoursite.com/default.aspx?stuff=2` to get *stuff* as parameter the code is

```
string stuff=Request.Params["stuff"];
```

Note that the value is stored as a string.

Comment: I get an error Error: The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: probably a missing namespace add `using System.Web;` to the top of the class.

Comment: I have the following: using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;

Comment: weird. What IDE are you using?

Also is your class inheriting from System.Web.UI.Page?

Comment: I am using MS Visual Studio 2012; cant they make an IDE that can suggest namescapes?

Comment: look, I've created a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=fe6CKfNL) with an extract from a codebehind of an aspx page.

Comment: fra9001, the op asked "how is this done in asmx?", so the Request object will be available as such: "HttpContext.Current.Request.Params", but is not really applicable for this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Server.Transfer("admin.aspx?SelectedView=view1", true);
```

You can get the passed variable using the above code.

```
    String selectedView = Request.QueryString["SelectedView"];
```